# In julia functions : passed by reference or value?

Tags: julia

In julia how do we know if a type is manipulated by value or by reference?

In java for example (at least for the sdk):

- the basic types (those that have names starting with lower case letters, like "int") are manipulated by value
- Objects (those that have names starting with capital letters, like "HashMap") and arrays are manipulated by reference

It is therefore easy to know what happens to a type modified inside a function.

I am pretty sure my question is a duplicate but I can't find the dup...

**EDIT**

This code :

```
function modifyArray(a::Array{ASCIIString,1})
    push!(a, "chocolate")
end

function modifyInt(i::Int)
    i += 7
end

myarray = ["alice", "bob"]
modifyArray(myarray)
@show myarray

myint = 1
modifyInt(myint)
@show myint
```

returns :

```
myarray = ASCIIString["alice","bob", "chocolate"]
myint = 1
```

which was a bit confusing to me, and the reason why I submitted this question. The comment of @StefanKarpinski clarified the issue.

My confusion came from the fact i considred += as an operator , a method like push! which is modifying the object itself . but it is not.

`i += 7` should be seen as `i = i + 7` ( a binding to a different object ). Indeed this behavior will be the same for `modifyArray` if I use for example `a = ["chocolate"]`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The corresponding terms in Julia are [*mutable*](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Mutable-Composite-Types-1) and [*immutable* types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Composite-Types-1):

- immutable objects (either `bitstype`s, such as `Int` or composite types declared with `immutable`, such as `Complex`) cannot be modified once created, and so are passed by copying.
- mutable objects (arrays, or composite types declared with `type`) are passed by reference, so can be modified by calling functions. By convention such functions end with an exclamation mark (e.g., `sort!`), but this is not enforced by the language.

Note however that an immutable object can contain a mutable object, which can still be modified by a function.

This is [explained in more detail in the FAQ](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#I-passed-an-argument-x-to-a-function,-modified-it-inside-that-function,-but-on-the-outside,-the-variable-x-is-still-unchanged.-Why?-1).

Comment: The key fact, however, is that all values are manipulated by reference.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002572/creating-copies-in-julia-with-operator, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235597/julia-function-argument-by-reference.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski Thanks, it is clear. I had just confused myself ... I've edited my question in case someone else falls in the same trap

Comment: Just pointing out the statement "immutable objects [...] are passed by copying" is only true for `isbits` types. e.g. `a = "hello"; f(x) = pointer(x); pointer(a) == f(a) #true, passed by reference`. It's just that they're immutable, so you can't really do much to them inside a function. But you *could* alter it via unsafe_pointers etc if you really wanted to, so the distinction matters.

Comment: Also, that certain immutable objects are passed by copying is an implementation detail. From the user's perspective, all arguments are passed by sharing.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most rigourous answer is the one in

[Julia function argument by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235597/julia-function-argument-by-reference%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B)

> Strictly speaking, Julia is not "call-by-reference" but "call-by-value where the value is a
>   reference" , or "call-by-sharing", as used by most languages such as
>   python, java, ruby...