# Weird set index error

Tags: julia

I am stuck on this chunk of code

```
hdiag = zeros(Float64,2)
hdiag = [0,0]
println(hdiag)
hdiag[1] = randn()
```

In the last line I obtain an `InexactError`. 
It is strange because randn() it's a `Float64`, but for some reason I have to do `hdiag=randn(2)` and then there should not be a problem.

Comment: xref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002572/creating-copies-in-julia-with-operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line:

```
hdiag = [0,0]
```

*changes* `hdiag` to refer to a completely new and different array than what it was before.  In this case, that new array is an integer array, and so any subsequent assignments into it need to be convertible to integers.

Indexed assignment is different; it changes the contents of the existing array.  So you can use `hdiag[:] = [0,0]` and it will change the contents, converting the integers to floats as it does so.  This gets even easier in version 0.5, where you can use the new `.=` dot assignment syntax to assign into an existing array:

```
hdiag .= [0,0]
```

will do what you want.  For more details on arrays, bindings, and assignment, I recommend reading this blog post: [Values vs. Bindings: The Map is Not the Territory.](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2014/09/06/values-vs-bindings-the-map-is-not-the-territory/)