# Passing expressions by reference inside expressions

Tags: metaprogramming, julia

I am fairly new to Julia, so apologies for any misunderstandings of the language I may have.  I have mostly used Python recently, and made heavy use of SymPy and its code generation features, and it seems like Julia with its metaprogramming features is built for writing code in exactly the kind of style I like.

In particular, I want to construct block matrices in Julia from a set of smaller building blocks with some different operations in between.  For debugging purposes and because the various intermediate matrices are used in other calculations, I want to keep them as expressions containing variables, such that I can quickly loop over and test different different inputs, without wrapping everything in a function.

Now, for a minimal case study, say I have two expressions `mat1 = :a` and `mat2 = :b` that I want to combine to form a new, third expression:

```
mat3 = :($mat1 + $mat2)
```

The above method works fine *until* I modify `mat1` and `mat2`, in which case I have to re-evaluate `mat3` in order to reflect this update.  This is caused, I presume, by the fact that `$mat1 + $mat2` is not passing `mat1` and `mat2` by reference, but rather interpolates the expressions inside at the time of evaluation of that line.  The behaviour I want to achieve is that `mat1` and `mat2` are not inserted until I call `eval(mat3)`, preferably with minimal boilerplate.

Is it possible to achieve this in a handy syntax?

Comment: `mat3` will reflect the *mutation* of `mat1` and `mat2`, but not *rebinding* of `mat1` and `mat2`. It is important to understand the distinction between mutation and rebinding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mat3` will reflect the *mutation* of `mat1` and `mat2`, but not *rebinding* of `mat1` and `mat2`. It is important to understand the distinction between mutation and rebinding.

### Mutation

Mutation occurs when the data of an object is modified. Note that this does not affect any *names*, only *objects*. This can manifest in many ways, including functions like `push!` and assignment syntax with a complex left-hand side, like `A[1] = 5`.

For example, all of the following are examples of *mutation*:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
A[1] = 4
```

The name A is unchanged; A still points to the same object. The *object* that `A` represents is modified.

```
A = :(f(x))
A.args[1] = :g
```

The name A is unchanged; A still points to the same object. The *object* that `A` represents is modified.

```
mat1 = :(f(x))
mat2 = :(f(y))
mat3 = :($mat1 + $mat2)
mat1.args[1] = :g
```

The name `mat1` is unchanged; it still points to the same object. That object is modified. `mat3` references that same object also, and because it's been modified, it will reflect the changes. Indeed, now `mat3` contains `:(g(x) + f(y))`.

### Rebinding

(also known as assignment)

Rebinding occurs when *no object data is modified* but the target of a name is changed to that of a different object. This is indicated by a simple `=` assignment, with the left hand side being the thing rebound.

```
x = 2
x = 3
```

Here `x` is being rebound from the object `2` to the object `3`. We are not *changing* the object `2`. In fact, because `2` is an *immutable* object, it is not allowed to mutate the object `2`. Instead, the reason the observable value of `x` has changed is because it references a different object now: `3`.

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
A = [4, 2, 3]
```

Once again here we are not *mutating* the vector `A`; we're creating a new vector and now `A` references this new vector. Distinguishing between mutation and rebinding is important. Once again, mutation acts on *objects*, and rebinding acts on *names*.

```
mat1 = :x
mat2 = :y
mat3 = :($mat1 + $mat2)
mat1 = :z
```

Note here that the simple assignment does not *mutate* the object `:x` that `mat1` references; it simply rebinds `mat1` to the different object `:z`. This means that `mat3`, which contains the object `:x`, will not be affected.

Note that `Symbol` is an **immutable** type, so you cannot mutate it. Thus it is impossible to do what you're proposing.

A better way to do what you're proposing is to use a function instead of a single expression. A function can be called multiple times, producing different objects.

```
mat1 = :x
mat2 = :y
mat3() = :($mat1 + $mat2)  # function definition
mat3()  # :(x + y)
mat1 = :z
mat3()  # :(z + y)
```

Comment: It would be even better to make mat3 take mat1 and mat2 as parameters.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002572/creating-copies-in-julia-with-operator/33003055#33003055. I have to agree with David Sanders – what's with the aversion to using functions? This is exactly what they're for. Metaprogramming in this situation is going to be uniformly worse (slower, more confusing, harder to reason about).

Comment: I think I have overestimated what I could do with metaprogramming. The reason for not wanting to use functions is that I want to construct large matrices representing molecular systems, where each element becomes an enormous analytic expression which should ideally subsequently be simplified to a) get faster expressions, b) let me evaluate whether the constructed matrix makes sense and which factors disappear and c) store the expressions for later use. However, I probably got overexcited about metaprogramming, when I probably actually need a CAS/SymPy-like package for that, right?