# Julia: array assignment behaviour

Tags: arrays, julia

My question is about the change of array elements.
Consider the following code snippet:

```
julia> a = [1 2; 3 4]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> b = a
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> a[1,1] = -1
-1

julia> b
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 -1  2
  3  4
```

However, when I run the following instead:

```
julia> a = [1 2; 3 4]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> b = a
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> a = [5 6; 7 8]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 5  6
 7  8

julia> b
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

Array `b` remains unchanged? Why is that, can anyone explain this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating copies in Julia with = operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002572/creating-copies-in-julia-with-operator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first example, you are creating an array and assigning a pointer to that array to `a`. You then assign the same pointer to `b` in line 2, so that `a` and `b` are references to the same memory location. When you mutate an *element* in the array, you do not change where `a` and `b` are pointing, so that both `a` and `b` both reflect the new value in the first memory offset within the array.

In the second example, you create an array and assign a pointer to `a`. You then assign the same pointer to `b`, just as before, but you next create a new array in a different memory location and assign *that* location to `a`. `a` and `b` are now pointing to two different memory locations, each with their own arrays.

Here's a demonstration:

```
julia> a = [1 2; 3 4]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> pointer(a)   # show the memory location of the array
Ptr{Int64} @0x000000011cd1a120

julia> b = a
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> pointer(b)   # note - same memory location
Ptr{Int64} @0x000000011cd1a120

julia> a = [5 6; 7 8]
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 5  6
 7  8

julia> pointer(a)    # note - new array; new memory location
Ptr{Int64} @0x000000011d259e80

julia> pointer(b)    # still referencing the first array's location.
Ptr{Int64} @0x000000011cd1a120
```

Comment: The words _pointer_ and _reference_ aren't quite right and will likely confuse folks who know them from other languages.  I'd replace them with _binding_ or _naming_.  See JMW's classic blog post: [Values vs. bindings: the map is not the territory](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2014/09/06/values-vs-bindings-the-map-is-not-the-territory/).

Comment: Also x-ref to this Metaphor: [A Table of Boxes and Forms and Colorful Stickers](http://blog.leahhanson.us/post/julia/variables.html).