# array variables in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I've encountered something curious with array variables. Suppose I create

`A=[1. 2;3 4]` and then define `B=A`. If I then set `A[1,1]=7`, the `[1,1]` entry in `B` changes. But if I set `A=ones(2,2)`, the entries in `B` do not change.

Any comments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating copies in Julia with = operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002572/creating-copies-in-julia-with-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B=A` assigns `A` to `B` and does **not** create a copy. Therefore `A` and `B` both point to the same piece of memory. Changing something in `B` will inevitably also alter `A` and vice versa. `A` and `B` are *identical*, to be checked with `A === B` (note the three equal signs).

You can create a copy of `A` by `C = copy(A)`. Note that in this case `A == C` but `A !== C`, i.e. they have the same entries but aren't *identical*.

`A = ones(2,2)` allocates a new 2x2 array and fills it with ones (`ones(2,2)`) and afterwards assigns this array to `A` (`A = ...`). Therefore any connection to `B` is lost. Note that if you would do `A .= ones(2,2)` (note the dot before the equal sign which indicates in-place assignment) you would also alter `B`.

Comment: @Jeff Also note that if your array has array elements, eg `[[1,2],[3,4]]`,  then you would need to use `deepcopy` to get a truly independent variable, since `copy` only creates new values at the first level of nesting.