# Julia 1.0.2.1: Why is a variable changing value, without being assigned?

Tags: julia, atom-editor

I am building a metaheuristic in Julia for study purpose.

The purpose is to find the best order of boxes.

1) I start with an initial order (random order) defined as. Order = InitOrder before my while loop.

2) For each iteration in the while loop I set CurrentOrder = Order

3) When the CurrentOrder is changed, Order changes too. Why does Order change value without being assigned? And how do I avoid it?

Version:
JuliaPro 1.0.2.1

Editor: Atom

```
        while ( (time_ns()-timestart)/1.0e9 < RunLength && done == false ) #Stopping Criteria
            done = true #Starting point
            IterationCount = IterationCount + 1
            BestCurrentValue = sum(H) #Worst case solutio
            CurrentOrder = Order #(From,To)

            for n1=1:N
                for n2=1:N
                    if n1 != n2
                        (CurrentOrder,CopyTo) = SwapBox(CurrentOrder,n1,n2) #Swap boxes
                        (CurrentLayout,L) = DeltaCopy(CurrentLayout,CopyTo,CurrentOrder) #Delta Copy to minimise calculations

                        (TempLayout,L) = BLV(BinW,CurrentLayout,CopyTo,CurrentOrder,W,H,L) #Evalueate by BLV
                        if L < BestCurrentValue #check if TempLayout is better than Best Current
                            BestCurrentValue = L
                            BestCurrentOrder = CurrentOrder
                            BestCurrentLayout = CurrentLayout
                        end #if L<...
                    end #if n1 != n2
##############################################################################
                    CurrentOrder = Order
##############################################################################
                end #n2 in N
            end #n1 in N

            if BestCurrentValue < BestValue
                done = false #Look further
                BestValue = BestCurrentValue
                BestOrder = BestCurrentOrder
                BestLayout = BestCurrentLayout
                Order = BestOrder
            end #if BestCurrentValue...

        end #while
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating copies in Julia with = operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002572/creating-copies-in-julia-with-operator)

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment `NewOrder=Order` does not copy any information in memory, it just says that the variable `NewOrder` should point to the same memory location as `Order`. Changing one of these variables will thus also change the other. If you want to copy a variable you could use `NewOrder=deepcopy(Order)`