# Julia function unwittingly modifies its argument without ! - help me understand this behaviour?

Tags: function, julia

I do not understand this behaviour of Julia. Somehow, the arrays `xit` and `mut` are connected at the hip and share values in the following MWE below:

```
sample_size = 100;
mc_reps = 100;
ka = .01;
threshold=1;
mut = Array{Float64}(undef,mc_reps,sample_size);
xit = mut;
mut[:,1] = ones(mc_reps);
function regime_prob(ka,ce,muu)
   h = 1/(1+ exp(ka*(ce-muu)))
   return h
end
xit[1,1] = regime_prob(ka,threshold,mut[1,1]);
xit[:,1] = regime_prob.(ka,threshold,mut[:,1]);
```

I tried declaring the function inline like so: `regime_prob(ka,ce,muu) = 1/(1+ exp(ka*(ce-muu)));`

which made no difference. Is there a subtle idiom I am invoking unwittingly?

I expected the `mut` array to keep its columns of ones but somehow the value of the `xit` keeps getting written into it.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Being lazy, I think the line hit = mut is at fault. I thought it would be overwritten?

Comment: Maybe `hit = copy(mut)` will be helpful?

Comment: The exclamation point in function names isn't syntactical, it's just a convention

Comment: @DanGetz is correct - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55885804/variable-duplicates-and-copies-in-julia) for further info.

Comment: You should have a look also at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150295/how-to-pass-an-object-by-reference-and-value-in-julia     I propose to mark your question as a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case this doesn't get closed as a duplicate, the correct answers are hiding in the comments to your question:

1. Assignment in Julia does not copy, so `xit = mut` means `xit` is now just another name referring to the same object as `mut`:

```
julia> x = rand(5); y = x;

julia> x === y
true
```

2. If you do want to copy, use `copy(mut)`
3. The `!` suffix to a function name in Julia is just a syntactical convention - you can write a `myfunction(x)` that mutates `x` just as well as a `myfunction!(x)` that doesn't, but both of these are discouraged because they are likely to confuse the reader.