# After the assignment "b = a", when does changing "a" in Julia also changes "b" and when it does not?

Tags: julia, variable-assignment, mutation

Suppose I have run the assignment `b = a` in Julia. Then I change `a`.

In what cases does `b` change automatically and when not?

### Notes

The answer to [Creating copies in Julia with = operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002572/creating-copies-in-julia-with-operator) covers the same central topic with different implications and fewer examples. This question seems *not* to appear in a search by someone who already knows that an assignment is not a "copy" in Julia. (I wrote my question and answer because it did not appear in my own search.) For those people, my question will be useful. Besides, the answer is easier to understand, and refers to the linked question at the end.

The use of "change" in the question is deliberately ambiguous. It reflects "a common confusion (in) the distinction between assignment (...) and mutation" as stated in [https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables/#man-assignment-expressions:~:text=A%20common%20confusion%20is%20the%20distinction%20between%20assignment%20(giving%20a%20new%20%22name%22%20to%20a%20value)%20and%20mutation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables/#man-assignment-expressions:%7E:text=A%20common%20confusion%20is%20the%20distinction%20between%20assignment%20(giving%20a%20new%20%22name%22%20to%20a%20value)%20and%20mutation).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Then I change `a`"?  Did you _assign_ it?  Did you _mutate_ it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating copies in Julia with = operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002572/creating-copies-in-julia-with-operator)

Comment: @JohnGordon   The use of "change" in the question is deliberately ambiguous. The answer clarifies the ambiguity. The last example in the answer: If the change is brought by `a = [4 5 6]`, we have an assignment.  If the change is brought by `a .= [4 5 6]`, we have a mutation. The ambiguous question represents the problem in the heads of people who get confused.

Comment: @SundarR Yes, but this answer did not seem to appear in a search by someone who already knows that an assignment is not a "copy" in Julia. Regarding the answers, I think mine is easier to understand. It also shows how broadcasting effects mutation, not assignment. Explaining the difference between `=` and `.=` makes the clarification stronger. Thank you for the link - I included it at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assignment vs Mutation

Suppose that, after running the assignment `a=[1,2,3]`, we run the assignment `b=a`. Both `a` and `b` are names that point to the same space in memory where the array `[1,2,3]` resides. (The same effect results from the chained assignment `b=a=[1,2,3]`.)

The mutation `a[1] = 42` changes the mutable structure `[1,2,3]` to `[42,2,3]`. Now, both `a` and `b` refer to the new value `[42,2,3]`.

A subsequent assignment `a = 3.14159` does not change the array `[42,2,3]`. It simply binds the name `a` to a different object (a scalar) that lives in a separate memory location. The array `[42,2,3]` is still accessible via the name `b`. Thus, executing `a` makes the REAPL display `3.14159`, and executing `b` makes the REAPL display `[42,2,3]`.

Therefore, after `b=a`, where `a` is a mutable structure, any mutation of an *element* of `a` affects the value returned by `b`. If the change in `a` is not a mutation but the assignment of a separate value to the name `a`, the value returned by b continues to be the same. Moreover, if all the *elements as such* of `a` are changed, so are the elements of the mutable structure returned by `b`. Example:

```
x = [1 2 3] ;

y = x       ;

x .= [4 5 6];    # Broadcasting changes the elements. The name x is not bound to a separate array.

julia> print(x)                                                                                                                                                           
[4 5 6]

julia> print(y)
[4 5 6]          # Therefore, y returns the same array with modified elements.
```

Compare the previous block of code with the next:

```
x = [1 2 3] ;

y = x       ;

x = [4 5 6];    # Julia binds the name x to a separate array.

julia> print(x)                                                                                                                                                           
[4 5 6]

julia> print(y)
[1 2 3]          # Therefore, Julia did not modify the array y refers to.
```

Please, read the answer to [Creating copies in Julia with = operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002572/creating-copies-in-julia-with-operator) by one of the creators of Julia.